# Synonym für "Auf seiner Seite stehen"

Tags: synonym

Ich schreibe gerade eine Karte und möchte der Person vermitteln dass ich ihm immer den Rücken stärken will - also wenn er es schwierig hat im Leben bin ich für ihn da. Dazu fällt mir nur ein

"auf seiner Seite stehen",

das hat aber Implikationen die ich so nicht vermitteln will (vor kurzem Scheidung, ich will nicht sagen dass ich auf seiner Seite stehe, und damit als "Gegner" des Partners auftrete). Fällt jemandem eine gute Formulierung dazu ein?
LG, Jakob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Du könntest zum Beispiel sagen

> Du kannst auf meine Unterstützung zählen.

oder kürzer

> Du kannst immer auf mich zählen.

Das könnte natürlich trotzdem noch Unterstützung **gegen** die andere Person sein, insofern ist die Implikation nicht völlig verschwunden, aber zumindest sind keine Seiten explizit ausgemacht.

Alternativ:

> Meine Tür steht dir immer offen.
>
> Falls du Hilfe benötigst, bin ich für dich da.

Answer (score 1):

> Ich habe immer ein offenes Ohr für dich.
>
> Ich bin für dich da

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit einer anderen Präposition?

> *An* seiner Seite sein

(mit "stehen" weniger üblich)

> Ihm *zur* Seite stehen